# The way to give reason by giving reasons for that reason

Tags: sentence-construction, repetition

> The table shows 80% of correct fixings. In contrast to correct fixings, there are some incorrect fittings mainly **because of** missing lines or distorted graph relations **due to** the absence of small segments, mismatch of parameters or under-segmentation.

I feel this is bit odd and as I don't have experience with explaining this type of case. I am looking for some assistance with modifying this in a more formal way to present this idea.

Comment: Your question is **very** confusing as written. That said, there is nothing wrong with the ***because of .. due to*** construct you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complex situation which will tax even fairly sophisticated native-speaker writers. There are four techniques which can help you:

1. Don't let phoney 'style' considerations prevent you from repeating terms.
2. Employ uncontracted structural devices—repeated prepositions,
   for instance, or frank *either ... or* constructions—to make
   the 'shape' of your argument more evident.
3. Employ the full range of punctuation as a structural device—use colons and semicolons, and don't try to get too much into one sentence.
4. Outline your argument, so *you* are clear where you are going:

   - 80% of 'fixings' are correct
   - Most of the rest are not correct for one of two reasons

     1. Some are incorrect because lines are missing
     2. Others are incorrect because graph relations are distorted
   - Distorted graph relations are caused by:

     1. The absence of small segments
     2. Mismatched parameters
     3. Under-segmentation

Now all you need is a little tweaking.

> The table shows that 80% of 'fixings' are correct. The rest are incorrect, mostly for one of two reasons: either lines are missing or graph relations are distorted. Distorted graph relations are caused by the absence of small segments, by mismatched parameters, or by undersegmentation.